# What can you look for to ensure that a vegan restaurant is Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, restaurant, vegetables

Vegan restaurants claim to serve strictly vegetable and plant-based meals.

They would seem to be automatically Kosher, but I've read and heard that there could be other Kosher issues.

What are those issues, and what are some things you can do to ensure that a vegan restaurant is not involved in any of them?

Comment: Bugs, bugs and more bugs. the salads are not generally cleaned well enough that would ensure the lettuce and broccolli, and other veg. to be clean of bugs. It doesn't help that you can't see them.

Comment: Grape products are your biggest concern

Comment: @Nafkamina But Vegans don't eat bugs either

Comment: @Imray Apparently (based on Nafkamina's comment) some Jews think that bugs you can't see are still prohibited. I doubt vegans are so strict.

Answer (score -1):

A kashrut certificate.

As per the comments above, there are likely issues with grapes and bugs. As such, even a vegan restaurant requires certification to be kosher.

Comment: -1 This should be a comment, except that it adds nothing to the existing comments

Comment: This question has been marked a duplicate; you might want to think about moving your answer over to the original question; but before you do, please realize that the other question asked this question with a lot more detail than this one did, so your answer will probably need to be edited to match, first.

Comment: @Imray I exactly answered the question...what can you do to make sure the restaurant is kosher.

Comment: @Shokhet yup I agree the other answers over there are more useful. (while maintaining that I answered the question as it was posed here). If I chose not to move it over because the answers there are sufficient, am I supposed to leave this here, or delete my answer?

Comment: @andrewmh20 You can leave it here, it's fine (I think).

Comment: @andrewmh20 What you answered is the equivalent of a answering a computer question with "call tech support" and claiming it in fact is a valid working solution

Comment: @Imray no, it is more like someone asking how to do a certain math problem, implying they wish to so it simply and he hand , and I say "use wolfram alpha". I did not show them how to solve it like they wanted to, but I answered the question of how to do it, and conveyed the point that there is no good and easy way to do it by hand.